# Spring Data Cosmos DB Sql API - findByTimestamp?

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I want to query the cosmos db sql api container using JPA methods in my Spring boot application.

I am using spring data Cosmos DB SQL Api.

I want to sort the records by the timestamp field "`_ts`" , and get the latest "n" no. of records.

I know i can page/sort like this :
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.limit-query-result

But how do i sort based on the DB-Generated timestamp ?

Comment: Any updates from your side?